# Xcode 4.5 - Can't create Branches/Trunks/Tags for SVN

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, xcode4.5

Simply as titled, I can't create Branches/Trunks/Tags for SVN although I am able to connect to the repo. In the screen where I enter the Trunks, Branches and so, it can't connect to them (showing red indicator). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the branches, tags, and trunk folders exist in the repo? Is this a local or remote repo? For local repos I had success in the past by going to the project folder in the Finder and adding the branches, tags, and trunk folders manually. I moved the project files to the trunk folder and imported the project from Xcode. But it's been a while since I used svn with Xcode so things may have changed.

Comment: Are you able to create folders if you select the Root folder from the Organizer and click the New Directory button at the bottom of the Organizer? If not, can you create the folders from the Terminal or another svn client? If you can create the folders outside Xcode that would let you know it's an Xcode problem and not a problem with creating folders remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Source Control->Project Name->COnfigure
Over there, select configuration and update the paths of trunk,
tags and branches.
Now along with info and configuration, you'll get branches option as well/
From there add a new branch and an auto switch to that branch will happen.