# Xcode 7 create a branch for SVN ios project

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, xcode7

I need to create a branch for SVN project in xcode. I need to know what is trunk, tags and branches under xcode working copies configure.

How do i create a branch in Xcode editor? or i need to do only in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Below is basic understanding for terms you required.

**Trunk**: The trunk is a directory where all the main development happens and is usually checked out by developers to work on the project.

**Tags** : The tags directory is used to store named snapshots of the project. Tag operation allows to give descriptive and memorable names to specific version in the repository.

For example, LAST_STABLE_CODE_BEFORE_EMAIL_SUPPORT is more memorable than

Repository UUID: 7ceef8cb-3799-40dd-a067-c216ec2e5247 and

Revision: 13

Branches: Branch operation is used to create another line of development. It is useful when you want your development process to fork off into two different directions. For example, when you release version 5.0, you might want to create a branch so that development of 6.0 features can be kept separate from 5.0 bug-fixes.

You could go through this tutorial for all basic concept and branching stuff.

Reference Link :

1. [SVN tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/svn/svn_basic_concepts.htm)

2. [Create new branch in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041/how-do-i-create-a-branch-in-svn)

/*----- UPDATE ------*/

Below is screenshot for creating new branch via XCode.

[image: New branch in Xcode]

Comment: Steps to create a branch trough Xcode? or we have to do through terminal only?

Comment: @Cintu - You could first go through the different tutorial for understanding the working/commands of SVN. Also you could create branch and other stuff via Xcode or terminal depending upon your interest and easiness.

Comment: Thanks nikhil.But I couldnt find the way to create a branch through the xcode.

Comment: @Cintu - I have added a screenshot for creating new branch. Also my suggestion would be to go for terminal as thats easier once concept of version control is clear.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil. I am using xcode 7.1 instead of "New Branch" option i am having only Configure project in Source control section.

Comment: I am also using XCode 7.1 and in your case, it might be that you haven't configured your project for version control. Could you share your screenshot ? Also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837798/xcode-4-5-cant-create-branches-trunks-tags-for-svn) for configure thing and [Apple document for new branch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/CreatingaBranchinaRepository/CreatingaBranchinaRepository.html)